# #1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s) in Insert into Select

Tags: mysql, sql

hey Guys i m working on SQL and i got this error

first i ll show you my code

```
Insert into HistoriqueEquipement  (DateMHS,CodeEquipement,nomenclature) VALUES (2015-03-28, (SELECT  CodeEquipement,nomenclature FROM equipement WHERE Numero_Serie =241));
```

i got the error #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s); 
and if i use

```
  Insert into HistoriqueEquipement  (DateMHS,CodeEquipement) VALUES (2015-03-28, (SELECT  CodeEquipement FROM equipement WHERE Numero_Serie =241));
```

it work perfectly so where's the problem i want to insert many columns not only one

Comment: The error is because the subquery is returning two columns (`CodeEquipment` and `nomenclature`), and is supposed to be the values for one (`CodeEquipment`).  You'll need to break this into two subqueries, one for each column, or convert the query into a join to accomplish what you are trying to do

Comment: yes i know that it returns to Two but how i do that can explain more please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting this error as the `rows` returned by the `SELECT` is more than one. So you can use a `INSERT INTO TABLE SELECT` like this:

```
Insert into HistoriqueEquipement  (DateMHS,CodeEquipement,nomenclature) 
SELECT  CURDATE(), CodeEquipement, nomenclature 
FROM equipement 
WHERE Numero_Serie =241;
```

Comment: how to close the Question  !!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `insert . . . select`, and you can use it with a constant:

```
Insert into HistoriqueEquipement (DateMHS,CodeEquipement) 
    SELECT '2015-03-28', CodeEquipement
    FROM equipement
    WHERE Numero_Serie = 241;
```

Note:

- If you want only one row, then add `limit 1`.
- Even when using values, you need single quotes around the date.  `2015-03-28` evaluates to `1984` (think "subtraction").  This then gets treated as a date.

Answer (score 0):

> The Error You are Getting because Your Sub-Query `SELECT 
>   CodeEquipement,nomenclature FROM equipement WHERE Numero_Serie =241` 
>   Returning More than 1 result.

if you want to insert a single row to the table then you can try:

```
Insert into HistoriqueEquipement  (DateMHS,CodeEquipement,nomenclature) 
VALUES (2015-03-28, 
(SELECT  top 1 CodeEquipement,nomenclature FROM equipement WHERE Numero_Serie =241));
```

And if you want to insert all the record from `equipement` table to `HistoriqueEquipement` table.

then you can use: [Insert into select](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

```
Insert into HistoriqueEquipement(DateMHS,CodeEquipement) 
    SELECT '2015-03-28',CodeEquipement
    FROM equipement
    WHERE Numero_Serie = 241;
```